# How to troubleshoot installing Pop! OS with Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, dualboot, pop-os

I am trying to dual boot Pop! OS with Windows 10 on my PC, I have the disk partitions set up (about 50 GB for the new OS), as well as the .iso in a flash drive for booting.  But whenever I boot from the USB to go and install Pop! OS, the new OS cannot see the hard drive, it can only see the USB that is being used to boot the OS.

In the help section of the installation process, there is a tip that fast startup needs to be turned off, which I then did, but after trying to install the OS again, it still will not detect the hard drive.

Any help would be much appreciated.  I am using a Lenovo 81XH IdeaPad Flex.  Thanks!

Comment: Besides Fast Startup there are drive modes that aren't compatible, namely "RAID" and "Intel RST", it needs to be AHCI. But if you change to AHCI without installaing its support in Windows then Windows won't boot. And DON'T "set up" partitions for Linux (you can't do it from Windows), leave unallocated space (not a partition). Any previous partition intended for Linux must be formatted with a file system supported by Linux and Windows cannot create those. The Linux installer will do that in the unalloacted space.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Any idea where I can find some instructions on how to install the AHCI support for windows?

Comment: https://support.thinkcritical.com/kb/articles/switch-windows-10-from-raid-ide-to-ahci

Comment: This also might be if your boot media is using legacy and your existing OS is UEFI.  See this: https://www.google.com/search?q=drive+not+showing+EFI

Comment: "the new OS cannot see the hard drive" - Are you using MBR or GPT?  [edit] your question instead of replying with a comment